# Vim: Prevent console being automatically closed after an external command with ":silent"

Tags: vim

I want to execute external command, but unwilling to see the prompt

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

As a solution to this, I add 'silent' before the external command

```
:silent !<external command>
```

But this cause the console to be automatically closed after the command.

Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: You want to continue in the shell itself?

Comment: @SibiCoder Yes, in some cases I don't care about the return value from shell to vim, so I want the shell execute the command independently and "pause" when the command is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use `:sh` to go to shell from vim and then execute your commands and then give `exit` from shell to return back to vim.

This is different from quitting vim  with q and executing commands in shell and coming to vim again with `vim filename`.

How is it different?

1) By `:sh`, you can still move to shell without even need of saving changes. So, in case if you need to execute single shell command, you cant exit vim with several changes which you may or may not want to save.

2) By `:sh`, all the opened tabs and buffers in vim will remain and you can go to shell and return back.

Comment: Is this OK with your purpose or you want different one?

Comment: Your answer teaches me another way to open shell from vim in addition to ":!" command. But what about using gvim, when I want to execute shell command without gvim waiting for shell to exit? As I mentioned in the question, ":silent !<command>" will do this work, but the shell automatically closes after the shell command. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think we can control the shell from vim. So, it won't wait for your reply in shell. If you want to capture the output and see it, you can use `:echo system("shell command here")` to see the output of the specified shell command.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it's the case like what you said.